# How can I make this program give me a pytest assert which pass?

Tags: python, pytest, assert

I have a function `ejercicio5` that is supposed to process a list of lists. Each inner list contains elements, and the function should process these elements and create a specific output format. However, my test cases are not passing, and I suspect there might be an issue with my test setup.

```
def ejercicio5(s):
    for x in s:
        for z in x:
            print(z)
        print("***************")
```

Could someone please help me write working pytest examples for the ejercicio5 function?

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. If you've had a specific problem testing this function, give a [mre] _including the test_ (and the result of running it).

Comment: Please, give us some more supporting information : show us what test cases you already have, what is going wrong (error messages, expected output vs. real output, ...), etc. You can find out more about the information that would be good to include in your question at [ask].